# D3.js mouseover event should reach also the inner area of the circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have the following circle on my page.

[image]

```
container.append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("fill", "none")
        .attr("cx", x)
        .attr("cy", y)
        .attr("r", 10);
```

and the following event listeners on it.

```
svg.selectAll("circle")         
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        console.log("mouse over");  
    })                  
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        console.log("mouse out");
    });
```

**Mouse over** event is triggered when pointer is on red circle line and **mouse out** event is triggered when it goes out of the red circle line.

How can I make an event listener that triggers when mouse pointer passes on red circle line and the white inside area of it? Not just the red line. Now **mouse out** event is triggered when pointer is inside the red line (the white area inside the red circle). It should trigger only when pointer goes outside the circle.

Comment: I expect you'll need a secondary circle with an inner radius of zero that actually receives the events.

Comment: What code did you use to create the circle in the first place? It should be easier to help out with a bit more code :-)

Comment: I added the code that implements the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of fill `none`, use `transparent`.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",500);

var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("r",50)
  .attr("cx",60)
  .attr("cy",60)
  .style("fill","transparent") //Changed fill:none to fill:transaparent
  .style("stroke","red")
  .style("stroke-width","2");

circle.on("mouseover",function(){
  console.log("mouseover");
});      

circle.on("mouseout",function(){
  console.log("mouseout");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31472364/4235784) proposed by Gilsha you might stick to `fill: none;` and use the CSS property [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) setting it to `visible` instead.

> **visible**
>   SVG only. The element can be the target of a mouse event when
>   the visibility property is set to visible and the mouse cursor is over
>   either the interior (i.e., fill) or the perimeter (i.e., stroke) of
>   the element. The values of the fill and stroke do not effect event
>   processing.

The following example will render the circle's stroke in blue as long as the mouse pointer hovers over the stroke or the interior fill.

```js
d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr({
            "width": 200,
            "height": 200
        })
    .append("circle")
        .attr({
            "cx": 100,
            "cy": 100,
            "r": 50
        })
        .style({
            "fill": "none",
            "stroke": "red",
            "stroke-width": "20",
            "pointer-events": "visible"  // <--
        })
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.select(this).style("stroke", "blue");  
        })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            d3.select(this).style("stroke", "red");  
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```